# How do I get pandas update function to correctly handle numpy.datetime64?

Tags: pandas, datetime, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column that may contain `None` and another dataframe with the same index that has datetime values populated. I am trying to update the first from the second using `pandas.update`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'as_of_date': np.datetime64('2017-05-08')}])
print(df.as_of_date)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'as_of_date': None}])
print(df2.as_of_date)
df2.update(df)
print(df2.as_of_date)
print(df2.apply(lambda x: x['as_of_date'] - np.timedelta64(1, 'D'), axis=1))
```

This results in

```
0   2017-05-08
Name: as_of_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
0    None
Name: as_of_date, dtype: object
0    1494201600000000000
Name: as_of_date, dtype: object
0   -66582 days +10:33:31.122941
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

So basically `update` converts the datetime to milliseconds, but keeps the type as object. Then if I try to do date math on it, I get wacky results because numpy doesn't know how to treat it.

I was hoping `df2` would look like `df1` after updating. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [391]: df2 = df2.combine_first(df)

In [392]: df2
Out[392]:
  as_of_date  id
0 2017-05-08   0

In [396]: df2.dtypes
Out[396]:
as_of_date    datetime64[ns]
id                     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This works, thanks. What is the difference between `combine_first` and `update`? The documentation seems similar for both.

Answer (score 0):

A two step approach

1. Fill None data in df2 using date from df:

   df2 = df2.combine_first(df)
2. Update all elements in df2 using elements from df

   df2.update(df)

Without 2nd step, df2 will only take the values from df to fill its Nones.